# Current carrying conductor with a loop at a distance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

In Fig, there are an infinitely long conductive wire and a circle conductive loop C with the radius r and the number of turns n. The distance L between the wire and the loop is much larger than r, i.e., L >> r. The normal direction of the loop is x and the current I flows through the wire downwards. Under this condition, We want the magnetic field intensity due to I through the loop C to enhance. How should we make a current flow in the loop C? Draw the answer schematically in the answer sheet.

[image: Fig.]

**Now I have done some work on this question but it still wrong. my work is given below.**

**Answer**

Problem-1: From eq(1) we can see that magnetic flux Φ_B depends upon the distance L between a loop and a current carrying long wire. So decreasing the value of L magnetic field intensity can be enhanced.
[Since I is constant then we only have to change L to enhance the magnetic field intensity.]
Problem-2: If the current I through the infinite conductive wire is fixed and length L is also fixed, then we can make a current flow in the loop C (which must be a closed loop) by rotating it in y axis as shown in figure 4.1 and figure 4.2. Since according to Faraday's law, emf is induced in a closed loop of wire when magnetic flux linkage changes. That is, current flows through the closed loop. If there is no change (with time) in the number of lines of B field, or magnetic flux, through a closed loop (C) there will be no induced voltage set up as well as current in the loop.[image]
[image]

**But this far I am able to go. In general text book, the loop circuit is drawn as only a circle without a buttery, but in some text book, for simply, a circuit is only a loop wire. Current flowing is indicated by an arrow with the direction, which is nearby the loop. And also, the loop is connected with a buttery. But. the buttery is not shown in the figure because this is common in this study field.**

***how can i solve this problem***

Comment: This question should be reopened...